# Adjusted Gross Income for TurboTax

Tags: united-states, income-tax, turbotax, adjusted-gross-income

In order to file my taxes using TurboTax, I need by AGI (adjusted gross income) for 2019. Since I used form 1040, the adjusted gross income in on line 8b. However, when I downloaded the form, it is blank. Should I just put $0 for AGI?

Comment: where did you download the form from? The form you sent to the IRS last year wouldn't be missing this value.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep: From TurboTax

Comment: Did you file your taxes with TurboTax last year? Did you keep any copies that might have that information (perhaps it's just a glitch on their side).

Comment: To answer the question, you should not use $0 _unless you actually had zero AGI in 2019_. We have no idea if that was the case or not.

Comment: Don't download the (blank) form, open the filled form inside TurboTax.

Comment: Do you have the actual form you filed last year? You are supposed to keep a copy. If you don't have it, I believe you can still find it through IRS's website: https://www.irs.gov/individuals/get-transcript

Answer (score 1):

When you submitted your tax forms in the spring of 2020 for the 2019 tax year, you were advised to create a pdf file of the federal and state tax forms. This pdf will have the Adjusted Gross income.

If you imported last years tax file into this years tax software one of the numbers the software would have pulled into this years data file is the AGI for last year. I have found two places in TurboTax where the number is easily found.

Switch to the forms view and you should find two forms that the software creates:

- Tax history which shows this years numbers and the previous 4 years;
- and the Two Year Comparison form with details from this year and last year.

Both forms will have the Adjusted Gross Income.

If you didn't import last years tax file into the software and you still have the software and file from last year you can open the old software and find the number on the 1040 form.